# Game just gets stuck when I reload the scene in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have added a pause button in my game when you user touches it and restart the level, it should just reload the current scene, But it just gets stuck there and shows me this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX7Fb.png)

I cant seem to find the issue.I don't know where did that DontDestroyOnLoad object has come from. Pause button still works but nothing else do.
If anyone body can help?

Comment: post  your code in a question update.

Comment: code of what? Bro i start my game on main menu. i click play it loads the maingame scene okay? Than i pause game and go to main menu again. Than i hit play again and now the maingame scene is stuck again?

Answer (score -2):

When I paused the game I changed Time.timescale=0 but didnt change it to 1 when i restarted or reloaded or anything else. Just added a new script in camera for it. God bless.

Comment: That is what @ken was referring to with `post your code` .. without knowing that you are using the `Time.timescale` somewhere how where people supposed to answer?